# commiting different projects in netbeans to different svn branches

Tags: svn, netbeans-7

We are using netbeans 7 with svn as the version management tool. Right now Netbeans has a team tab where I go and set the URL of the SVN repositiory server. I wanted to know if I can have a different URL for each project in netbeans. i.e. instead of associating the URL with the whole netbeans in team tab can I associate the svn url server per project? 

**Edit**: Just read about tagging, so another option if possible would be to keep the URL same for multiple project versions and checkin checkout in each project happens to the appropriate sub branch in SVN server. is this possible?
Thanks in advance..
Regards, 
Priyank

Answer (score 2):

You can manage each project in netbeans in different subversion repositories... http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#opening

Comment: On a side note - I Think there is a slight glitch with Netbeans as I have the main trunk and a branch.  I was working with a local copy of the branch and in Netbeans the subversion window only showed changes in the trunk project.  I had to right-click on the project in Netbeans project and select Show Changes from the Subversion menu.